# Best books for understanding pathophysiology

Tags: practice-of-medicine, reference-request, pathophysiology

Please  recommend some books on advanced pathophysiology that are accurate and simple.

Comment: There are no books on advanced pathophysiology that are simple.

Comment: Need not be simple then... concepts should be advanced... please comment if you know any

Answer (score 3):

I really liked the pathology textbook [Robbins & Cotran Pathologic Basis of Disease](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1455726133).  I own the massive book, and it's pretty well written and not difficult to read, given that you have the science background to understand it.  Not that I could sit down and read it, I used it more as a topic reference, but I did have classmates who read the thing, kudos to them.

I loved [Pathoma](https://www.pathoma.com/) for a more straightforward, simplified, top-down approach to pathology. It solidifies fundamentals without too many details, which Robbins and other sources will certainly fill in for you.

The most comprehensive sources of advanced concepts are usually system-specific texts rather than a general pathology textbook.  For example, extremely advanced cardiac pathophysiology would be more extensively covered in cardiology-specific literature than in Robbins.

Note: This answer is opinion-based. Since Robbins is a fairly standard med school textbook, I think it's fair as an answer; Pathoma is just a very popular resource that I found to be great.